# Unable to write URL in mozilla firefox by using selenium script. Even eclipse doesn't show any error

Tags: java, selenium, testing, mozilla

Try to test the ikea home page by selenium script.Mozilla fire fox is open but url is entered in address bar.

```
package ikea;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ikeaautomation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        WebDriver driver ;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Users\\orange\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://ikea.in";
        String expectedTitle = "IKEA";
        String actualTitle = "";

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        // get the actual value of the title
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        /*
         * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
         * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
         */
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }

        //close Fire fox
        driver.close();

        // exit the program explicitly
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Answer to to your Question:

While you work with Selenium 3.4.0, geckodriver v0.17.0, Mozilla 53.0 through Selenium-Java bindings, instead of **`webdriver.firefox.marionette`** you have to mention **`webdriver.gecko.driver`** through `System.setProperty` as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\orange\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Rest your code works fine:

Modified Code:

```
    // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    // get the actual value of the title
    actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("Actual : "+actualTitle);
    System.out.println("Expect : "+expectedTitle);

    /*
     * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
     * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
     */
    if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
        System.out.println("Test Passed!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }
```

Console Output:

```
Actual : IKEA
Expect : IKEA
Test Passed!
```

Let me know if that Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks!! but after doing same modification getting error in console:
Usage:
    C:\Users\orange\Downloads\geckodriver.exe [OPTIONS]
C:\Users\orange\Downloads\geckodriver.exe: Unknown option --port=44135

Comment: Can you update your updated code block & the full error stack trace updated in the Question area please? Seems `geckodriver` is randomly trying to open port `44135` which is not available. Try restarting your system once. Thanks

Comment: Thanks!! after updating geckodriver and system restart it works